# Google Cloud Printer /register interface using c#

Tags: c#-4.0, google-cloud-print

I am trying to implement Google Cloud Printer /register interface using c#. I'm getting the below error:

```
{  "success": false,  "message": "Proxy ID is required.",  "request": {   "time": "0",   "params": {    "firmware": [     "1"    ],    "model": [     "CAAGB"    ],    "update_url": [     "test url"    ],    "manufacturer": [     "TestManufacturer"    ],    "support_url": [     "test url"    ],    "name": [     "TestPrinter"    ],    "proxy": [     ""    ],    "gcp_version": [     "2.0"    ],    "uuid": [     "uuid123"    ],    "capabilities": [     "{\"version\": \"1.0\"}"    ],    "setup_url": [     "test url"    ]   }  },  "errorCode": 115 }
```

Can you please suggest how to use GCP /register interface using c#?

Answer (score 0):

May be the proxy server is not assigning a proxy ID when you send a request.

Here's what proxy ID means:

http://www.ehow.com/facts_7474797_proxy-id.html